# Leaving everything you're doing for salat

Tags: salat, hadith-interpretation, food

Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu
Please clarify the following facts about salat. In my upbringing I was told that when the iqama is said you have to leave everything you are doing for the prayer but today someone quote an Hadith for me that:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If the Iqama for (`Isha') prayer is proclaimed and supper is served, take your supper first."
> ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5465) and other variations in  [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:557a), [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:672) and elsewhere)

The prophet of Allah said 'if dinner is ready and iqama is said, you should start with the dinner first'

So I want to ask is eating food better than praying

Jazakumul llahu khayran

Comment: @Can you site the exact hadith if possible? Maybe it's about a special circumstance such as Ramadan.

Comment: Hadith

أَخْبَرَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ مَنْصُورٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنْ أَنَسٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏

‏ إِذَا حَضَرَ الْعَشَاءُ وَأُقِيمَتِ الصَّلاَةُ فَابْدَءُوا بِالْعَشَاءِ ‏"

‏ ‏‏

It was narrated that Anas said:

"The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'If dinner is ready and the Iqamah for prayer is said, then start with dinner first."'

Sahih (Darussalam)

Sunan an-Nasa'i 853 
In-book : Book 10, Hadith 77 
English translation : Vol. 1, Book 10, Hadith 854
Sunan an-Nasai

Get Hadith Collection (All in one) App:https:/bhj

Comment: @SpiderRico I think that's the Hadith

Comment: No eating is not better than prayer see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:675). But the matter requires a a more detailed discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this hadith signifies is that khushoo' (focus) in prayer is more important than catching the congregation or praying at the earliest time. Scholars have explained that the reason behind the instruction of the prophet ﷺ is hunger, because when you leave food to pray first you might remain constantly distracted due to your desire, and so it is better to eat first and then pray in tranquility.

There are also other similar ahadith which excuse a person while they are distracted due to natural function of their body, for example while [suppressing](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/1/351) gas, or while under the dominance of [sleep](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:213).

> هذه الأحاديث كراهة الصلاة بحضرة الطعام الذي يريد أكله لما فيه من اشتغال القلب به وذهاب كمال الخشوع وكراهتها مع مدافعة الأخبثين وهما البول والغائط ويلحق بهذا ما كان في معناه مما يشغل القلب ويذهب كمال الخشوع
>
> <sup>— [Sharah Sahih Muslim ~  al-Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/989)</sup>